# SQL SUM only return values >=1

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a simple query which I only want to return values

```
SELECT advisor AS advisor,
SUM(`outcome` LIKE '%TPS_Approved%') AS approved
FROM shift_report 
WHERE `team`!=6 AND date>20150720 AND date<20150728
GROUP BY `advisor` 
ORDER BY `advisor`
```

I only want it to return advisor and approved count if the count is >=1

Comment: Simply add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` or `HAVING SUM(outcome LIKE '%TPS_Approved%') > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you want ?

```
SELECT advisor AS advisor,
count(*) AS approved
FROM shift_report 
WHERE `team`!=6 AND date>20150720 AND date<20150728 and `outcome` LIKE '%TPS_Approved%'
GROUP BY `advisor` 
ORDER BY `advisor`
```

Comment: Perfect Keorl, that does exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

One of posible options

```
SELECT A.advisor, A.approved
FROM (
    SELECT advisor,
    SUM(`outcome` LIKE '%TPS_Approved%') AS approved
    FROM shift_report WHERE `team`!=6 and date>20150720 and date<20150728
    group by `advisor` order by `advisor`
) A
WHERE
    A.approved >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for, note the `having` condition after the `group by` restricts your results based on the group totals.

```
SELECT advisor,
count(*) AS approved
FROM shift_report 
WHERE `team`!=6 
AND date between 20150720 AND 20150728 
and `outcome` LIKE '%TPS_Approved%'
GROUP BY `advisor`
HAVING count(*) >=1
```